# Unable to import name '_TPU_AVAILABLE' from 'pytorch_lightning.utilities'

Tags: import, tpu, downgrade

I'm trying to import aitexten package to work on a GPT-2 solution. But I'm encountering an error:ImportError: cannot import name '_TPU_AVAILABLE' from 'pytorch_lightning.utilities' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/**init**.py)

[image]

I tried downgrading pytorch to v1.11.0 but that isn't helping too. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Google Colab. And it's with `aitextgen` version 0.6.

```
!pip uninstall -qqy torch torchvision torchtext torchaudio fastai
!pip install -qq torch==1.9.0 pytorch-lightning==1.7.7 aitextgen==0.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem! I fixed it by downgrading `aitextgen`.

In the beginning of my notebook, I ran this command:

`!pip3 install -q aitextgen==0.5.2`

Make sure to restart your kernel.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! In my case v0.5.1 worked out for aitextgen

Comment: Thanks @SudesnaBaruah, this did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

try this  :

```
pytorch-lightning==1.4.0rc0
torchmetrics==0.6.0
aitextgen==0.5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case

`pip install -qq pytorch-lightning==1.7.7 aitextgen==0.6.0`

Fixed it.